# Activity with multiple Video tabs all play at once

Tags: java, android

I have an Android Activity that has multiple tabs which swipe left and right and contain either the YouTube API video connection or the direct video play. But as soon as I launch the activity, all of the videos in all tabs (except those having YouTube because they need to be clicked first) play automatically.

The same happens with the tabs having webpages showin in WebView. All of the webpages in all tabs automatically start loading as soon as the Activity is launched, thereby heavily impacting the performance of the mobile.

Is there any solution I can code so as to not to load the content in the tab until and unless the tab is visible and to stop all its content as soon as the tab is out of focus?

Comment: Could you post some snippets to show the structure of your XML and or code that's causing this?

Comment: There are a lot of files. Should I paste the snippet of Main Activity or the snippets from toolbar_default.xml and toolbar_tabbar.xml?

Comment: Try to boil it down to the simplest example that still exhibits the problem you are having. That'll be the easiest for us to help!